# How to keep the proper `this` context in JavaScript when using recursion, inheritance, and encapsulation

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, this

I am using ES6 in FF (native, I'm not using a translator). I have the following class setup:

[image: Class Diagram]

Note that I'm only showing relations in that diagram, not proper types and what-not.

The Canvas class represents an HTML5 canvas, and the Ellipse class represents an Ellipse drawn on the canvas. The goal I have here is that I can move my mouse on the canvas, and get events on the shapes I draw, such as the ellipse. Since the question is not in regards to the event translation, please assume that that works just as well as you would expect with HTML elements. However, I will note that the `_propagate` call is what handles this, and it works with recursion (explained later).

The full definition of `subscribe` looks just like `addEventListener`: `(eventName, callback, [isCapture])`.

Inside of canvas, I have the following code:

```
addObject(object){
    this.__children.unshift(object);

    console.log("Susbscribing to " + object.toString());
    object.subscribe(MouseEventType.MouseDown, this.objectMouseDown);
}
// ...
canvas.addObject(new Ellipse());
```

So, I add an ellipse to Canvas, and when I do that, I subscribe to the ellipse's MouseDown event. Note that at this point, the `console.log` will output "Subscribing to Ellipse"

Now, for the subscribe code is this:

```
subscribe(eventName, func, useCapture = false){
    // If the event exists, add the method, otherwise, throw an exception
    if(this._subscribers[eventName]){
        this._subscribers[eventName][useCapture].push(func);
        console.log(this.toString() + " has had somebody subscribe to " + eventName);
    }
    else{
        throw eventName + " is not a valid event";
    }
}
```

And again, at this point, the `console.log` correctly identifies the object as Ellipse.

Finally, we get to the `__dispatchEvent` code, which is the following:

```
 __dispatchEvent(eventName, eventData, isCapture = false){
    if(this._subscribers[eventName] && this._subscribers[eventName][isCapture]){
        for(var func of this._subscribers[eventName][isCapture]){

            // Set the sender to `this`
            console.log("Sending " + eventName + " event from " + this.toString());
            eventData.sender = this;

            // setTimeout = run in new thread
            // Really weird syntax so things are kept in scope correctly
            // -- func is passed into an anonymous method, which then calls that function with the event data
            ((f) => setTimeout(() => f(eventData), 0))(func);
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, I want to click on the Ellipse, and I should get the following flow:

- Mouse Click Detected on HTML5 Canvas Element, and it sent to Canvas class
- Canvas class dispatches MouseDown capture event to itself
- Canvas calls `_propagate` on the Ellipse
- Ellipse dispatches both the capture and bubble event to itself  << **Problem lies here**
- Canvas dispatches the bubble event to itself

Simple enough, and pretty much works just like the mouse events in HTML.

So, the problem is that in my callback, I have this code:

```
objectMouseDown(e){
    console.log(e.sender.toString());
}
```

I'm expecting that I should be logged "Ellipse" again, however, I'm getting "Canvas" instead.

A couple things to note:
- The dispatcher says that it is sending the Ellipse mouse-down event
- The call to the callback doesn't seem to happen until after the Canvas get's a callback for its MouseDown (while bubbling)
- If I remove the subscription the the Canvas MouseDown, then the Ellipse MouseDown does get called correctly.

Here is a log dump with the standard setup:

```
> Sending MouseDown event from Ellipse    << From the dispatch
> Sending MouseDown event from Canvas     << From the dispatch
> Canvas                                  << From the event handler
```

And, if I remove the MouseDown on Canvas

```
> Sending MouseDown event from Ellipse    << From the dispatch
> Ellipse                                 << From the event handler
```

Please let me know if I didn't explain something well enough. I'm guessing that this has something to do with JavaScript's `this` being really weird. However, I've been unable to figure out how to store it properly. I even tried setting a member variable to be `this` when the subscription happens, since things are correct at that level, but that didn't work. And at this point, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with `this` specifically, but with the fact that you are deferring the execution of the event handler *and* that you are sharing `eventData` between multiple `__dispatchEvent` calls.

Since you defer the execution of the handler until the next tick, every handler gets the same `eventData.sender` value.

That's exactly what you see in the output:

```
> Sending MouseDown event from Ellipse    << From the dispatch
> Sending MouseDown event from Canvas     << From the dispatch
> Canvas                                  << From the event handler
```

The second call will set `eventData.sender` to the canvas object, hence when `f(eventData)` is called afterwards in the next tick, `eventData.sender` will refer to the canvas object.

In a comment you are saying

> setTimeout = run in new thread

but that's not correct. `setTimeout` adds the function to a queue. The queue is processed whenever the thread is idle, i.e. in your case after all `__dispatch` methods have been called. You can learn more about the processing model [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

---

Without knowing more about your code, a simple solution would be to defer setting the sender until the handler is called:

```
__dispatchEvent(eventName, eventData, isCapture = false){
    if(this._subscribers[eventName] && this._subscribers[eventName][isCapture]){
        // Use `let` for block scope
        for(let func of this._subscribers[eventName][isCapture]){
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Set the sender to `this`
                console.log("Sending " + eventName + " event from " + this.toString());
                eventData.sender = this;
                func(eventData);
            }, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to pass a new instance of `eventData` to every handler.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with just putting everything in the `setTimeout` for now.